# Font redering problem after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, display, language-support

I upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. When the installation has finished and I restarted the names in my file manager, the information in the settings are displayed in gibberish! I'm confused what to do. HELP PLEASE!

[image]